# Java non-event monitoring

Tags: java, monitoring

I work for a company that has a java based eCommerce site. We have a new initiative to monitor when things aren't happening when they should be, such as guests not signing in and lack of completed orders.  For example, we expect x amount of orders at y time of day and when they are below the standard deviation we want to know about this through an alerting system.  We are already monitoring (the solutions we use are below) the health of the application and have a pulse on exceptions being thrown.  We are looking to catch when the app appears to be in good working order, but events we expect to be triggered aren't happening.  For example - our credit card authorizer could start declining all of the credit authorizing attempts so no orders are coming through, etc.

We are capable of building this ourselves, probably with Drools, but would prefer to find an out of the box solution.  In our research we have not found anything that really fits what we are looking for and didn't find the functionality in we are already using.  If any of the monitoring solutions we already use are capable of delivering this functionality that would be the route we would prefer.

- dynaTrace
- Truesite
- Hyperic
- Coremetrics analytics

Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: Opensource?  Free? Commercial?

Comment: Any of the above.  Preferably a solution we could buy support for.

Comment: We've used NewRelic,  though is not precisely cheap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have dynatrace then go with it. It can do all of what you are looking for. It can monitor your Credit Card Service and alert you in case reponse time goes down or in case it throws errors. It goes much broader than that use case - it actually tells you which end users are affected - whether this is just for certain types of users (from a certain region, from a certain type of device, ...) or if it is for everyone.
If you have questions on how to use dynatrace for your use cases I suggest you put a question on the dynatrace community forum - they are pretty active over there: https://community.compuwareapm.com/community/display/DTFORUM/dynaTrace+Forums+Home
You can also watch some of the video tutorials on youtube to make yourself more familiar with its capabilities: http://bit.ly/dttutorials

Comment: I watched a webinar that you had put on [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ysh_HL8HDoA&index=11&list=PLqt2rd0eew1bmDn54E2_M2uvbhm_WxY_6]  and found exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for your help!